# не работает slick-slider при помoении его в другой div

Tags: html, css, slider, slick.js

`

```
<div class="row">
                    <div class="slider-classic">
                        <div class="slider-classic-block"><span class="slider-classic-block-span">
                                <h1></h1>
                                <p></p>
                                <button class="button-blue-classic"></button>
                            </span></div>
                        <div class="slider-classic-block"><span class="slider-classic-block-span">
                                <h1></h1>
                                <p></p>
                                <button class="button-blue-classic"></button>
                            </span></div>
                        <div class="slider-classic-block"><span class="slider-classic-block-span">
                                <h1></h1>
                                <p></p>
                                <button class="button-blue-classic"></button>
                            </span></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

`

В чём пробемма ,если кратко то создал слайдер как положенно (до этого уже делал не раз) н тут ничего не работает если на пальцах то так

div class="row"

div class="slider"

```
  слайды
```

/div

/div

Но если вынести слайдер из div с классом row ,тобеж slider не пренодлежит другим div то всё начинает работать как надо
Просто вынести не вариант будет слишком много искусственных перемещений

Comment: Нужен подробный код, с настройками слайдера.

Comment: Можешь привести, пожалуйста, пример кода?)

Comment: добавил пример кода